# Xcode Create new Folder/Group Shortcut?

Tags: xcode, directory, shortcut, xcode10

is there a Xcode shortcut for creating new Folders/Groups ? I don´t like to always right click and then clickung create new folder.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use  **option + command + N**

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) btw. nice nice app name haha. Is It possible to directly change that name of the group? I have to click on the folder like normal to edit it